# How to add a UIScrollView to a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uialertview

I want to have a `UIScrollView` that is inside of my `UIAlertView`. Code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use -addSubview, however, I'd recommend you don't. Apple intends alert views to be simple, informational, and be quickly dismissed. Thus, aside from the fact that it would look pretty unsightly, it would be against the spirit, if not the letter, of the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Actually, look at the Wifi indicator. Its fine, as long as it is easy to use.